# Why is Javascript button not working?

Tags: javascript, css, html

The effect I am trying to achieve is that when I click a button (called about), one of the div (id=homepage) gets hidden and another div (id=intro_page, which was previously hidden) is made visible.

I have the following HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/index_script.js'></script>
.
.
<input onclick="clicked_about()" type="button" value='About'></input>
.
.
.
<div id="homepage">
     content
</div>
<div id="intro_page" style="display: none">
        <h1 id="intro_page_caption"> About Me </h1>
        <div id="intro_main_text">
            <p> I enjoy reading, swimming, jogging, painting and exploring. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="intro_pic1">
                <figure>
                <img src="img/my_picture.jpg" alt="My Picture" height="250">
                <figcaption>My Picture</figcaption>
                </figure>
        </div>
</div>
```

Following is the JavaScript Code:

```
function clicked_about(){
   document.getElementById(homepage).style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById(intro_page).style.display = 'block';
}
```

What I am seeing is that the code is hidden (because in HTML display is set to none), but when I click the button, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter to `getElementById()` is a string. So assuming you did not set some (global) variables `homepage` and `intro_page`, your `clicked_about()` function should look like this:

```
function clicked_about(){
   document.getElementById('homepage').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById('intro_page').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: @Strukt With just changing the function as I mentioned, but using an `<input>` or a `<button>` element with the `onclick` attribute works: http://jsfiddle.net/db6gp31p/ However, I think, that assigning the callback using JS code is better. But in that case use `addEventListener()` and not the `onclick` property.

Answer (score 1):

I did some changes in your code check this :)

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var mybutton = document.getElementById("mybutton");
    mybutton.addEventListener("click",function(){
       
       document.getElementById("homepage").style.display = 'none';
       document.getElementById("intro_page").style.display = 'block';
   });
}
```

```html
<button id="mybutton" type="button">About</button>

<div id="homepage">
     content
</div>
<div id="intro_page" style="display: none">
        <h1 id="intro_page_caption"> About Me </h1>
        <div id="intro_main_text">
            <p> I enjoy reading, swimming, jogging, painting and exploring. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="intro_pic1">
                <figure>
                <img src="img/my_picture.jpg" alt="My Picture" height="250">
                <figcaption>My Picture</figcaption>
                </figure>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just enclose the ids in quotes:

```
function clicked_about(){
   document.getElementById("homepage").style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById("intro_page").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Otherwise `homepage` and `intro_page` are variables, and therefore undefined, unless you previously defined them elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The function `getElementById` accepts parameter in string format. Wrap you Id in `"` and it will work

```js
function clicked_about() {
  document.getElementById("homepage").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("intro_page").style.display = 'block'; // missing quotes here
}
```

```html
<button onclick="javascript:clicked_about()" type="button">About</button>
<div id="homepage">
  content
</div>
<div id="intro_page" style="display: none">
  <h1 id="intro_page_caption"> About Me </h1>
  <div id="intro_main_text">
    <p>I enjoy reading, swimming, jogging, painting and exploring.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="intro_pic1">
    <figure>
      <img src="img/my_picture.jpg" alt="My Picture" height="250">
      <figcaption>My Picture</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick=function(){clicked_about();};
```

with

```
<button id="btn">About</button>
```

---

here is a JFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/upujp2q9/