# Javascript Button not responding

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

Am new to Javascript and was following this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3GVXEa_1r8&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hgNu5zXbGctiCWYebxjdeey&index=5&t=0s)

Which connected the android app to fireabse web app.
but the login button in firebase web app does not respond when clicked.
it produces the following error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined
    at app.js:11
(anonymous) @ app.js:11
errors.ts:101 Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
    at l (http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/6.6.1/firebase-app.js:1:10041)
    at Object.i [as auth] (http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/6.6.1/firebase-app.js:1:9592)
    at http://localhost:5000/:41:22`

i tried using the onclick function which i got from [Why is Javascript button not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583061/why-is-javascript-button-not-working) but it still did not respond.

i also tried using `firebase init` then `firebase serve` in place of `http-server`  but that also did not work

```
<body class="bg-dark">
  <script src="/__/firebase/6.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

          <script src="/__/firebase/6.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>

    <div id="login-card" class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h1>Admin Panel</h1>
            <form id="login-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button id="btn-login" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script>

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
            if(user){
                window.location.href = "admin.html";
            }
        });

    </script>

</body>
```

app.js

```
var firebaseConfig = {
...
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL; 

$("#btn-login").click(function(){

    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val(); 

    var result = firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    result.catch(function(error){
        var errorCode = error.code; 
        var errorMessage = error.message; 

        console.log(errorCode);
        console.log(errorMessage);
    });

});
```

Comment: Did you put a debugger and checked it?

Comment: do you get any errors in the browser **developer** tools console?

Comment: I just tried using the developer tools and this is what i get `Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined
    at app.js:11
(anonymous) @ app.js:11
errors.ts:101 Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
    at l (http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/6.6.1/firebase-app.js:1:10041)
    at Object.i [as auth] (http://localhost:5000/__/firebase/6.6.1/firebase-app.js:1:9592)
    at http://localhost:5000/:41:22`

Comment: Thanks fixed the problem it turns out that i had set the wrong paremeter on  firebase.initializeApp(config)  as config instead of firebaseconfig

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap with `$(document).ready()` in order to make it work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-login").click(function() {
    console.log("It's working");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn-login" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
```

---

**OR**

You need to bind event on `document` with selector

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn-login', function() {
  console.log("It's working");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn-login" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  it turns out that i had set the wrong paremeter on  firebase.initializeApp(config); as config instead of firebaseconfig